# Python: getting elements out of strange list that are 1.0?

Tags: python, regex, gurobi

So I'm using the Gurobi optimizer, and my decision variables are in a list called decision_bi, that looks like this:

```
<gurobi.Var dc0_st0_1/0 (value 0.0)>
```

I have managed to filter these down to the ones with the variable name containing '_1/0' with the following (I think):

```
matching = filter(lambda x: '_1/0' in x, decision_bi)
```

But now, I need to extract only those of this matching list that have (value 1.0), like so:

```
<gurobi.Var dc5_st1099_1/0 (value 1.0)>
```

I have managed to get it into a flat list (I was having issues with it being only accessible by decision_bi[i][j].X and .VarName which was not cooperating), and am trying regex on filtering on the 1.0 numbers with the following code:

```
import re

flat_list=[]
for sublist in matching:
    for item in sublist:
        flat_list.append(item)

results=[]
for i in len(flat_list):
    results[i] = re.search('.*?1\\.0', flat_list[i], flags=0)
```

However, it is telling me that the list is not iterable... and I don't know why? Using type on flat_list returns a list. 
My ultimate goal is writing two different lists containing the numbers after the dc and st parts of the string in the middle to our database, if it matters.

Comment: Why are you not using `results.append`?

Comment: I suppose I could, but I still get the "int object is not iterable"

Comment: Please add the traceback. Appending to a list is not iterating it. `i` is the only int in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply both the "1/0" and "value 1.0" checks in a single regular expression:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: pattern = re.compile(r"<gurobi\.Var .*?_1/0 \(value 1\.0\)>")

In [3]: pattern.match("<gurobi.Var dc0_st0_1/0 (value 0.0)>")

In [4]: pattern.match("<gurobi.Var dc5_st1099_1/0 (value 1.0)>")
Out[4]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 39), match='<gurobi.Var dc5_st1099_1/0 (value 1.0)>'>
```

Note that we needed to bask-slash-escape a literal dot and opening and closing parenthesis since they have a special meaning in a regular expression syntax.

If you have a list of variables like this, you can use a *list comprehension* to filter them out:

```
In [5]: values = [
    ...:     "<gurobi.Var dc0_st0_1/0 (value 0.0)>",
    ...:     "<gurobi.Var dc5_st1099_1/0 (value 1.0)>",
    ...:     "<gurobi.Var dc5_st1099_2/0 (value 2.0)>"
    ...: ]
In [6]: [value for value in values if pattern.match(value)]
Out[6]: ['<gurobi.Var dc5_st1099_1/0 (value 1.0)>']
```

Comment: A `gurobi.Var` is a class... I think the question is seeing the str or repr

Comment: @cricket_007 ah, did not know that..I hope the solution can still be applied with a tweak..thanks!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the Gurobi documentation isn't very straightforward to find what data is wanted

Comment: Gurobi's documentation is crap :P this helps optimize a part of it but doesn't resolve the list error >_>

Comment: Thank you! This led me to realize that my original list construction was screwed up, it was saying it was a string but it wasn't apparently, so I forced the string type onto it during list construction. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the string representation. Instead, create your list based on the [VarName](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/varname.html) and [X](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/x.html) attributes of the [Var](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_var.html) object, ex:

```
myVars = [v for v in model.getVars() if v.X == 1.0 and '_1/0' in v.VarName]
```

Comment: Okay, I was just answering a regex question :) This, though, looks better.

Comment: Agreed. Don't expect the string representation to give the float values. For example, the string might truncate some digits of precision.